# xcode4 documentation for iOS 4.3 Library

Tags: xcode4

I installed xcode4 and in Organizer - Documentation I can see **iOS 4.3 Library**, **Mac OS X 10.6 Library** and **Xcode 4.0 Developer Library**. However, when I'm offline, I cannot access the iOS library documentation, I'm getting **Error Loading URL** You are not connected to internet. For the other 2 libraries it works.

Anyone knows why it happens like that? There's no "get" button anymore in XCode > Preferences > Documentation.

Answer (score 4):

open the link feed://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone4_3.atom
find the properly file for your iOS 
after finishing download copy the xar file to path /Developer/Documentation/DocSets/ and unzip
it "sudo xar -xf *.xar" and unzip *.docset "sudo chown -R -P devdocs"

Comment: I think this is the right approach. Ultimately you get a document set that can be viewed inside or outside of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the iOS 4.3 Library is downloaded later. When you are online go into Preferences for Xcode and select Documentation. You will see that library is likely disabled but ready to be downloaded. If that is the case there will be a "Get" button on the right side which you can use to start the download which may take a while.

Once it is downloaded you will be able to use that documentation library when you are offline.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! However, I had a software update on my mac and that solved the iOS 4.3 Library issue, i don't know how... It downloaded it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get the documentation offline but could not find the "get" button.So I had to go to Preferences->Downloads->Documentation->Check and install now and then the new libraries showed up.Its better to check the "Check for and install updates automatically"

Answer (score 1):

Arguably simpler than any of these is to manually add the RSS feed for the documentation - at the bottom of the documentation download list is a `+` / `-` set of controls.  Click `+` and paste in `feed://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone4_3.atom` and it'll automatically select the right one and start downloading (and notify you of updates, though I doubt there will be any more)