# Apple previous documentation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xcode4 documentation for iOS 4.3 Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529788/xcode4-documentation-for-ios-4-3-library)

I am searching for apple previous(ios 4) documentation guides.Apple has changed all the documentation for storyboard.But I needed for xib.Where can i find previous(ios 4) documentation guides and other material.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Interface Builder is essentially the same between the two. The primary difference is that Storyboards include transitions. Can you explain what kind of info you are looking for that is lacking?

Comment: @chuk I want to develop app in xib so i am searching for reference guides where xib is used.Storybord are not compatible with previous ios so i can not use them

Comment: The answer given by "Groxx" to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529788/xcode4-documentation-for-ios-4-3-library seems to work well if the iOS 4.3 Library is not shown in the Documentation tab of the Xcode preferences.

Comment: It is showing error saying id and password is not in your keychain and its not showing any option for entering it. Where to fill id and password.Please Help?

Answer (score 1):

If I open Xcode Preferences, choose Downloads and the Documentation tab, I see a list of documentation sets that I can download.  iOS 4.3 Library is one of those.  Then, when I'm searching in the Organizer window, I can limit which sets it should use for results.

Comment: @philip i am not getting option for  iOS 4.3 Library in my xcode  download option.It shows for  iOS 6.0 Library.I am using xcode 4.5.Can you please explain how will I get option for iOS 4.3 Library.Thanks for your response..

Comment: That's odd...I don't remember doing anything special to get it.  (Xcode 4.5.2)  If you click the "Check and Install" does it become an option?

Comment: I have one computer where the iOS 4.3 Library is shown in the Documentation tab, and on a different (newer) computer it is not shown. I assume that the iOS 4.3 Library is only available if it was installed by a previous Xcode version. - But see this answer for a solution, that seems to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13504521/1187415

Comment: It is showing error saying id and password is not in your keychain and its not showing any option for entering it. Where to fill id and password.Please Help?